# How can I get Share intent result?

Tags: android

I'm using next code for sharing:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.share_text));
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,getResources().getString(R.string.share_via)), REQUEST_SHARE_RESULT);
```

- I want to get result of share intent How can I do ?
- How can I get Share intent receiver device Specifications?

Answer (score 1):

In the Activity you start your Intent from you have to overwrite onActivityResult

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thank's How can I get Share intent receiver device Specifications?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by Share intent receiver device specifications. But *Intent i* in the methods parameters is the actual Intent you started the Activity with.